# Graphs updating dynamicly via WebSocket on Android

Tags: android, graph, websocket

i have been looking for something similar but i havent found anything yet.

I want to make an android application that the UI is just a WebView. In this WebView I will have graphs (line chart, pie... whatever you can imagine). I was looking for this and there are a lot of examples:

1. [highcharts.com](http://www.highcharts.com)
2. [rgraph.net](http://rgraph.net)
3. google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/index
4. g.raphaeljs.com/

This graphs should be running in the WebView. I want to make them change with data I will read them from a Bluetooth or WiFi thread. So they must be dynamicly update. For this communication, I have thought the best idea is a WebSocket that communicates with the thread which is reading from the Bluetooth or WiFi.

I know WebView by default doesn't support websockets, but there is no problem on the use of libraries.

Can anyone link me a tutorial or an example so i can develop this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several statements that could help you:

- You can't use websocket protocol over bluetooth, as well there is not tcp (at least available for you). You have to write your own protocol over bluetooth one.
- [Java implementation](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) of websocket's protocol (both - server and client)
- [Java (android) library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) for drawing charts on Android
- If you will drop bluetooth support (I really don't understand how you can use it? Share chart from other device?) you can use this [library](https://github.com/knowledgecode/WebSocket-for-Android) + don't forget that websockets supported in Android's webview 4.4+
- If you don't need real time charts refreshing, you can always implement timer which will ask for new data every N seconds
- If you want to have normal, responsive application - do it native

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Thanks for the websocket implementation. The library for drawing charts i already got it. I will implement the bluetooth support. The use of it is just reading data from the inputstream. I will be reading data from there.

Comment: You are welcome. If it answer helped you - put +1 here. If it solved your problem - mark as right answer.  For more information about how this site works - http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: It actually helped. But i still cannot do what i pretended to do. ;( I am new in this web so i cannot vote +1 or -1 yet... Sorry. And thank you again.

Comment: Ask new concrete question about your problem and somebody will help.